# How can I add a suffix to my jaxb generated java beans using jaxb2-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin

From I third party I imported xsd's and a wsdl as contracts for their services. I am generating the beans with the maven-jaxb2-plugin . Because of naming collisions in my project I want to add suffixes to the bean names generated.

This is my plugin configuration in the :

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jaxb2.maven.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <xjbSources>
                        <xjbSource>src/main/resources/bindings.xjb</xjbSource>
                    </xjbSources>
                    <sources>
                        <source>src/main/resources/xsd</source>
                    </sources>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

And this is my bindings.xjb file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:jaxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"
        xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
        version="3.0">

    <jaxb:globalBindings>
        <!-- All beans should extend this base class: -->
        <xjc:superClass name="my.project.xml.MyXmlObject"/>
        <!-- No need for bigint -->
        <jaxb:javaType name="long" xmlType="xs:nonNegativeInteger"
                       parseMethod="my.project.xml.TypeConverter.parseLong"
                       printMethod="my.project.xml.TypeConverter.printLong"/>
    </jaxb:globalBindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

The project builds fine like this, and beans are generated.

I have found some code like, but it gives errors:

```
<jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="my.project"/>
            <jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
                <jaxb:elementName prefix="My" suffix="Dto"/>
                <jaxb:typeName prefix="My" suffix="Dto"/>
            </jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
```

I get the error:

```
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: The "jaxb:schemaBindings" customization is not associated with any schema element.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're missing the `schemaLocation="myxsd.xsd"` in the `schemaBindings` section

For example, according to your configuration, you should try to add

```xml
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="xsd/myxsd.xsd">
  <jaxb:schemaBindings>
    <jaxb:package name="mypackage"/>
    <jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
      <jaxb:elementName prefix="My" suffix="Dto"/>
      <jaxb:typeName prefix="My" suffix="Dto"/>
    </jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
  </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Tested against a simple test project with package set to `po` and got the [following result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owrY5.png)

Regards

**EDIT 13th february 2024**

You can in fact use `schemaLocation="*"` to apply to every file in the current XJC context.
But this option also tries to apply to binding file, it then fails.
Filling new issue

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got it to work for a single xsd as well. Unfortunately there are 100'rds of xsd's so I hoped there was a general solution for all of them. As far as I could see in the documentation, there is not. Wildcard in the schemaLocation is not allowed.

Comment: I've created an issue in jaxb-ri and PR proposal (see my edit above) to be able to set it in globalBindings. Hope this will be adopted

Comment: That's great! Can you share the PR link with me, then I'll support it.

Comment: PR here : https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/pull/1780
Issue here : https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/issues/1779

Comment: @BarbetNL : you said that `*` / wildcard in the schemaLocation is not allowed. Did you try `schemaLocation="*"` ?

Comment: I don't remember exactly all changes. I did try wildcards for location in different forms I think. But I swallowed my defeat and went with default naming and refactored my code base accordingly.

Comment: If your code is still there, could you try with `*` wildcard only for `schemaLocation` ? If it works, I'll update my answer and close my PR which would be irrelevant :)

Comment: No, I'm afraid not, I have moved on from this project a long time ago. I'm pretty sure I tried the wild card.

Comment: I've just tested `*` option : it doesn't work since it tries to apply the `schemaBindings` part to binding file. Filling new issue in jaxb-xjc